# Is there a way to place a button on a certain cell?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I would like to place a button on certain cells. A button which does not cover the whole cell, since I've already done that.

Current - This only creates a button which covers the whole cell, I would just like a little button on the side of the cell.

```
For x As Integer = 0 To gridCategories.Columns.Count - 1
            If gridCategories.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value.ToString = "master" Then
                gridCategories.Rows(x).Cells(0).Style.Font = New Font("Calibri", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
                gridCategories.Rows(x).Cells(0) = New DataGridViewButtonCell
            End If
        Next
```

Thank you,

Comment: Show us what have you tried, and what failed with it, so we can help you from there.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I've not tested this code. Hopefully it will get you headed in the right direction.  One option is to play with the padding...

```
Dim ButtonPadding As New Padding(4, 5, 6, 7)

For x As Integer = 0 To gridCategories.Columns.Count - 1
  If gridCategories.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value.ToString = "master" Then
      gridCategories.Rows(x).Cells(0) = New DataGridViewButtonCell
      gridCategories.Rows(x).Cells(0).Style.Font = New Font("Calibri", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
      gridCategories.Rows(x).Cells(0).Style.Padding = ButtonPadding 
  End If
Next
```

Note that the order of the padding is (top, right, bottom, left)